# Rendering the component in the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three files mydetails.js , myinfo.js and App.js. In mydetails.js i used arrow fucntion with props.In myinfo.js ,i imported mydetails.js. In myinfo i used class and component. I have captured all the props of the mydetails.js in a list through map method. I have return the list by converting into the string in the return method of myinfo.js. I have imported this myinfo.js into the App.js . Through Route  with component ={myinfo} i tried to render.

// App.js file

```
import Myinfo from './Layout/Myinfo';
class App extends Component {

  render(){ 
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Info</a>
     <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><Link to="/">Home </Link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <Link to="/myinfo">Mydetails </Link></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><Link to ="/about">About </Link></li>
    </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span><Link to="/login">Login </Link>  </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
     <div className="App">
      <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/> 
      <Route path="/myinfo" component={Myinfo}/>
      <Route path="/about"  component ={About} />
      <Route path="/login"  component={Login}/>

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

//Mydetails.js file

```
const mydetails=(props)=>{

    return(
     <div className="details" >
         <h1> My Info</h1>
        <h2 id="info">FirstName :{props.firstname}</h2>
        <h2 id="info">LastName  :{props.lastname}</h2>
        <h2 id="info">Gender    :{props.gender}</h2>
        <h2 id="info">DOB       :{props.dob}</h2>
        <h2 id="info">Graduation:{props.degree}</h2>
        <h2 id="info">College    :{props.college}</h2>
     </div>

   )
};
export default mydetails;
```

// Myinfo.js file

```
import Mydetails from './Mydetails';
class Myinfo extends Component{

    state={
        details :[
          {firstname:'####', lastname:'####',gender:'###',dob:'#####', degree:'#####',
            college:'###'}

        ]
      };

      render(){
      const info=this.state.details.map(detail=>{
            return <Mydetails 
            firstname={detail.firstname}
            lastname={detail.lastname}
            gender={detail.gender}
            dob={detail.dob}
            degree={detail.degree}
            college={detail.college}

            />
          })
          const infostring=info.join(' ');      
        return(
             <div>
                 {infostring}
             </div>
          );
      } 

}
export default Myinfo;
```

I am getting [object object] instead of props

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the const infostring=info.join(' '); in Myinfo.js file and return info directly like this:

```
return(
  <div>
    {infostring}
  </div>
);
```

// Myinfo.js file

```
import Mydetails from './Mydetails';
class Myinfo extends Component{

    state={
        details :[
          {firstname:'####', lastname:'####',gender:'###',dob:'#####', degree:'#####',
            college:'###'}

        ]
      };

      render(){
      const info=this.state.details.map(detail=>{
            return <Mydetails 
            firstname={detail.firstname}
            lastname={detail.lastname}
            gender={detail.gender}
            dob={detail.dob}
            degree={detail.degree}
            college={detail.college}

            />
          })

        return(
             <div>
                 {info}
             </div>
          );
      } 

}
export default Myinfo;
```